# Transferring data with CoreBluetooth / L2CAP channel

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, l2cap

While trying to set a data transfer in `CoreBluetooth` using `L2CAP` channel.
I am having problems. On the sending side I have this function firing on the tap of a button:

```
@objc func sendL2CAPInfo() {
    print(#function)
    let value = "Hello L2Cap Stream data...",
    data = Data(value.utf8)
    outPutStream.open()
    print("outPutStream -> \(outPutStream.debugDescription)")
    let bytesWritten = data.withUnsafeBytes { outPutStream.write($0, maxLength: data.count) }
    print("bytesWritten = \(bytesWritten)")
}
```

When it is executed I see this in the Xcode debugging console:

```
sendL2CAPInfo()
outPutStream -> Optional(<__NSCFOutputStream: 0x282969b00>)
bytesWritten = 26
```

On the receiving side I have this function, also firing on the tap of a button:

```
@objc func receiveL2CAPInfo() {
    print(#function)
    let bufLength = 10
    var buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bufLength)
    inPutStream.open()
    let bytesRead = inPutStream.read(buffer, maxLength: bufLength)
    print("bytesRead = \(bytesRead)")
}
```

Still on the receiving side I also have this code:

```
// StreamDelegate protocol implementation.

func stream(_ aStream: Stream,
            handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
    print(#function)
    if aStream == inPutStream {print("Input-Stream")}
    if aStream == outPutStream {print("Output-Stream")}

    switch eventCode {
    case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
        print("Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable")
        receiveL2CAPInfo()
    case Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable:
        print("Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable")
    case Stream.Event.openCompleted:
        print("Stream.Event.openCompleted")
    case Stream.Event.endEncountered:
        print("Stream.Event.endEncountered")
    case Stream.Event.errorOccurred:
        print("Stream.Event.errorOccurred")
    default:
        print("Stream.Event.SOME-OTHER-THING-HAPPENED")
    }
}
```

When launching the receiving app (while the sending app is running) I see this in the Xcode debugging console:

```
centralManagerDidUpdateState
centralManager(_:didDiscover:advertisementData:rssi:)
centralManager(_:didConnect:)
peripheral(_:didOpen:error:)
2019-01-17 13:16:37.168700+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[857:127305] [CoreBluetooth] WARNING: Unknown error: 431
stream(_:handle:)
Input-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
stream(_:handle:)
Input-Stream
Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable
receiveL2CAPInfo()
bytesRead = 0
stream(_:handle:)
Input-Stream
Stream.Event.endEncountered
```

On the sending side, it seems that things go as expected, 26 bytes are written.
On the other hand on the receiving side we do not see the 26 bytes coming in.

What is wrong? I have never used `L2CAP` channel before, so I must certainly be doing something not good, but I have no idea what. Any recommendation on what to check or where to look at would be very much appreciated.

.....
After more digging into the subject, here is some more information.

Here is the code for for the stream(_ :handle:) function:

```
func stream(_ aStream: Stream,
            handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
    print(#function)
    if aStream == inPutStream {print("Input-Stream")}
    if aStream == outPutStream {print("Output-Stream")}

    if (aStream != inPutStream) && (aStream != outPutStream)
    {print("Some-other-Stream")}

    switch eventCode {
    case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
        print("Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable")
    case Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable:
        print("Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable")
    case Stream.Event.openCompleted:
        print("Stream.Event.openCompleted")
    case Stream.Event.endEncountered:
        print("Stream.Event.endEncountered")
    case Stream.Event.errorOccurred:
        print("Stream.Event.errorOccurred")
        if let error = aStream.streamError {
            print("Error:\n\t\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    default:
        print("Stream.Event.SOME-OTHER-THING-HAPPENED")
    }
}
```

Here is what can be seen in the debugger once the central app is started, before attempting to write anything:

```
centralManagerDidUpdateState
centralManager(_:didDiscover:advertisementData:rssi:)
centralManager(_:didConnect:)
peripheral(_:didOpen:error:)
2019-01-18 13:32:14.840892+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] WARNING: Unknown error: 431
stream(_:handle:)
Input-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
stream(_:handle:)
Input-Stream
Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable
stream(_:handle:)
Output-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
stream(_:handle:)
Output-Stream
Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable
centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)
centralManager(_:didConnect:)
peripheral(_:didOpen:error:)
2019-01-18 13:32:28.521320+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] WARNING: Unknown error: 431
stream(_:handle:)
Output-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
stream(_:handle:)
Input-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
stream(_:handle:)
Input-Stream
Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable
stream(_:handle:)
Output-Stream
Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable
2019-01-18 13:32:28.523746+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] No known channel matching peer <CBPeripheral: 0x281bc4a00, identifier = D73B08A0-E9BB-483B-8078-4A7F992E7565, name = Michel’s iPad, state = connected> with psm 192
centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)
centralManager(_:didConnect:)
peripheral(_:didOpen:error:)
2019-01-18 13:32:38.948090+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] WARNING: Unknown error: 431
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable
stream(_:handle:)
Output-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
2019-01-18 13:32:38.949889+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] No known channel matching peer <CBPeripheral: 0x281bc4a00, identifier = D73B08A0-E9BB-483B-8078-4A7F992E7565, name = Michel’s iPad, state = connected> with psm 192
stream(_:handle:)
Input-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)
centralManager(_:didConnect:)
peripheral(_:didOpen:error:)
2019-01-18 13:32:49.278142+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] WARNING: Unknown error: 431
stream(_:handle:)
Output-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable
2019-01-18 13:32:49.280093+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] No known channel matching peer <CBPeripheral: 0x281bc4a00, identifier = D73B08A0-E9BB-483B-8078-4A7F992E7565, name = Michel’s iPad, state = connected> with psm 192
stream(_:handle:)
Input-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)
centralManager(_:didConnect:)
peripheral(_:didOpen:error:)
2019-01-18 13:32:59.739338+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] WARNING: Unknown error: 431
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable
stream(_:handle:)
Output-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable
stream(_:handle:)
Input-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
2019-01-18 13:32:59.741111+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] No known channel matching peer <CBPeripheral: 0x281bc4a00, identifier = D73B08A0-E9BB-483B-8078-4A7F992E7565, name = Michel’s iPad, state = connected> with psm 192
centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)
centralManager(_:didConnect:)
peripheral(_:didOpen:error:)
2019-01-18 13:33:10.567965+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] WARNING: Unknown error: 431
stream(_:handle:)
Output-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable
2019-01-18 13:33:10.569722+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] No known channel matching peer <CBPeripheral: 0x281bc4a00, identifier = D73B08A0-E9BB-483B-8078-4A7F992E7565, name = Michel’s iPad, state = connected> with psm 192
stream(_:handle:)
Input-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)
centralManager(_:didConnect:)
peripheral(_:didOpen:error:)
2019-01-18 13:33:21.404162+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] WARNING: Unknown error: 431
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable
stream(_:handle:)
Output-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
2019-01-18 13:33:21.406243+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] No known channel matching peer <CBPeripheral: 0x281bc4a00, identifier = D73B08A0-E9BB-483B-8078-4A7F992E7565, name = Michel’s iPad, state = connected> with psm 192
stream(_:handle:)
Input-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)
centralManager(_:didConnect:)
peripheral(_:didOpen:error:)
2019-01-18 13:33:32.147567+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] WARNING: Unknown error: 431
stream(_:handle:)
Output-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable
2019-01-18 13:33:32.148884+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] No known channel matching peer <CBPeripheral: 0x281bc4a00, identifier = D73B08A0-E9BB-483B-8078-4A7F992E7565, name = Michel’s iPad, state = connected> with psm 192
stream(_:handle:)
Input-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)
centralManager(_:didConnect:)
peripheral(_:didOpen:error:)
2019-01-18 13:33:42.788001+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] WARNING: Unknown error: 431
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable
stream(_:handle:)
Output-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
2019-01-18 13:33:42.789921+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] No known channel matching peer <CBPeripheral: 0x281bc4a00, identifier = D73B08A0-E9BB-483B-8078-4A7F992E7565, name = Michel’s iPad, state = connected> with psm 192
stream(_:handle:)
Input-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)
centralManager(_:didConnect:)
peripheral(_:didOpen:error:)
2019-01-18 13:33:53.734140+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] WARNING: Unknown error: 431
stream(_:handle:)
Output-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable
2019-01-18 13:33:53.736063+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] No known channel matching peer <CBPeripheral: 0x281bc4a00, identifier = D73B08A0-E9BB-483B-8078-4A7F992E7565, name = Michel’s iPad, state = connected> with psm 192
stream(_:handle:)
Input-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)
centralManager(_:didConnect:)
peripheral(_:didOpen:error:)
stream(_:handle:)
Output-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable
stream(_:handle:)
Input-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable
2019-01-18 13:34:04.231561+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] WARNING: Unknown error: 436
centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)
centralManager(_:didConnect:)
peripheral(_:didOpen:error:)
stream(_:handle:)
Output-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable
stream(_:handle:)
Input-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable
2019-01-18 13:34:14.861939+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] WARNING: Unknown error: 436
centralManager(_:didDisconnectPeripheral:error:)
centralManager(_:didConnect:)
peripheral(_:didOpen:error:)
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable
stream(_:handle:)
Output-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
stream(_:handle:)
Input-Stream
Stream.Event.openCompleted
stream(_:handle:)
Some-other-Stream
Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable
2019-01-18 13:34:25.472075+0900 CBL2CAPCh_Central[571:80355] [CoreBluetooth] WARNING: Unknown error: 436
```

Comment: You can't open the input stream on the tap of a button. You need the stream to be already open before the data is sent and you wait for the callbacks with the data I the stream. You should show more code, but your peripheral should publish the channel and your central should open it.  Attach to the input/output streams on both sides in response to the peripheral delegate callback.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer brings a few questions to me. 1) If I tap the button to open the stream on the receiving side, before tapping the one to open the stream on the sending side; is it still not good? 2) Concerning the call back, I suppose you are talking about the stream(_handle:) function of the StreamDelegate protocol; but I have to admit I don't see much of that called, eventhough I have set outPutStream.delegate and inPutStream.delegate.
.....

Comment: .......
3) For the peripheral publishing the channel and the central opening it, I believe I am doing things about the way they should be done (without being 100% confident).

Finally I do not attach to the input/output streams. And about showing more code, which part of the code do I need to show?

Comment: Yes, you need to use the `stream(_ handler:)` function to know when there are bytes available.

Comment: You mean stream(_ handle:)? I just figured out how to make it called. As I mentioned earlier it was not called. I guess this is one more important step to make things work. I will update my post to narrow the question.

Comment: @Paulw11. I updated the post including new information. I still have the "bytesRead = 0" which I don't quite like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than attempting to open the stream when a button is tapped, you should open the stream when the channel is connected.  You can then use the stream delegate `hasBytesAvailable` event to determine that there are bytes to read.

It is important that you schedule the streams on the current run loop.

For example, to open the streams on a `CBCentral`:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didOpen channel: CBL2CAPChannel?, error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
        print("Error opening l2cap channel - \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    guard let channel = channel else {
        return
    }
    print("Opened channel \(channel)")
    self.channel = channel
    channel.inputStream.delegate = self
    channel.outputStream.delegate = self
    print("Opened channel \(channel)")
    channel.inputStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: .default)
    channel.outputStream.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: .default)
    channel.inputStream.open()
    channel.outputStream.open()
}
```

And then to handle the received data:

```
 func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
     switch eventCode {
        case Stream.Event.openCompleted:
            print("Stream is open")
        case Stream.Event.endEncountered:
            print("End Encountered")
        case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
            print("Bytes are available")
            if let iStream = aStream as? InputStream {
                let bufLength = 1024
                let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bufLength)
                let bytesRead = iStream.read(buffer, maxLength: bufLength)
                print("bytesRead = \(bytesRead)")
                if let string = String(bytesNoCopy: buffer, length: bytesRead, encoding: .utf8, freeWhenDone: false) {
                    print("Received data: \(string)")
                }
            }
        case Stream.Event.hasSpaceAvailable:
            print("Space is available")
        case Stream.Event.errorOccurred:
            print("Stream error")
        default:
            print("Unknown stream event")
    }
}
```

My full working example is available here: https://github.com/paulw11/L2CapDemo

Comment: OK. I will look closely into that demo.

Comment: In your demo the data transfer goes from the Central to the Peripheral, I assume this is an arbitrary choice of yours and you could have made the transfer go from the Peripheral to the Central. Am I right? Or does it have to be one way and not the other?

Comment: No, you have a pair of streams,  you can just as easily write from the peripheral to the central.

Comment: I am exploring your code and comparing with mine. It's a great help, thank you. You have this line working smoothly:

"let bytesWritten =  data.withUnsafeBytes { ostream.write($0, maxLength: data.count) }"

I have this similar line, giving me a lot of trouble:

"let bytesWritten = data.withUnsafeBytes { outPutStream.write($0, maxLength: data.count) }"
.....

Comment: .....
I have changed your code to make sure there was no external differences that could explain that. But I am still missing something. In your case bytes are written as expected (even when I modified the code). In my case I get various error messages like: "No known channel matching peer ... with psm 192" or "SocketStream write error [0x0]: 1 32" and a few more.

Comment: Have you successfully opened the stream and received the `openCompleted` event before trying to write to it?

Comment: Yes, I have opened the stream and received the openCompleted event before trying to write to it.
But I get a bunch of messages after, that I don't think shoud be showing up.
I have added in the post, my code for the stream(_ :handle:) function and what I can see in the debugger, before I try to write anything, I suppose it may help see where I could be making something unappropriate.

Comment: Are you holding a strong reference the Channel object in a property?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186901/discussion-between-michel-and-paulw11).

Comment: In case someone else is having trouble with the same kind of issues. This can be an example to get started: https://github.com/zaxonus/L2CAP-Channel-Get-Started